# Дата в пути сохранения media

Tags: python, django

День добрый. 
Вот конструкция

```
def get_upload_md_name(self, filename):
    if self.pub_date:
        year = self.pub_date.year
    else:
        year = datetime.now().year
    upload_to = upload_dir % (year, self.slug + '-' + filename)
    return upload_to
```

Как можно добавить в путь не только год но еще и месяц ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к я явно не вижу, что из себя представляет шаблон upload_dir. То предположу, что этот  шаблон принимает 4 параметра и возвращает строку, тогда его потребуется изменить на 5 параметров, чтобы месяц тоже пролез. После его изменения достаточно поменять код вот так:

```
def get_upload_md_name(self, filename):
    if self.pub_date:
        year = self.pub_date.year
        month = self.pub_date.month # Чтобы это не значило
    else:
        year = datetime.now().year
        month = datetime.datetime.now().month #Получаем month
    #Передаем month в параметры
    upload_to = upload_dir % (year, month, self.slug + '-' + filename)
    return upload_to
```

Comment: `upload_dir = 'news/%s/%s' ` Вот что из себя представляет
Но выдает ошибку с вашем примером

Comment: Разобрался. `/%s` забыл добавить в пусть.